# How to show and hide multiple forms on the same page?

Tags: jquery

I have few radio buttons that each is associated to a separate div.
Once user choose one, its associated div will be shown, the problem is that once I choose an option and its div is shown if I choose the next option, the style of previous div wont be hidden.

I think to solve this issue I should have a separate function to make all the divs hidden before showing the new one, but I am wondering if there is any other alternative to this.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
                $("input[name=options]:radio").change(function() {
                    alert($(this).val());
                 $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
                })
            });


   radio btns go here .... 
  <div id="1" style="display:none">
    ......
  </div>

  <div id="2" style="display:none">
    ....
  </div>
```

Comment: whether all forms in the page are associated with radio buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just hide the forms before showing the target form like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name=options]:radio").change(function () {
        $('form').hide();//you may have to improve this form selector if there are unrelated forms in the page
        $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
    })
});
```

---

Since div's are used without any way to group them add a new class to all the targetted divs like

```
<div id="1" class="form-ct" style="display:none">......</div>
<div id="2" class="form-ct" style="display:none">......</div>
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name=options]:radio").change(function () {
        $('.form-ct').hide();//you may have to improve this form selector if there are unrelated forms in the page
        $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
    })
});
```

Comment: sorry I am using div for styling, if I change your third line to div it would affect all the divs of the page

Comment: @J888 then please share your html so that we can see what to hide

Comment: @J888 is there a common class for all those `div`s that has to be hidden

Comment: @j888 as Arun mentioned, _you may have to improve this form selector if there are unrelated forms in the page_. <br/> Means you can add a class to all the divs that you want to toggle. Lets say the class name is "formToToggle", then you can say `$('div.formToToggle').hide();`

Answer (score 0):

As I have commented in Arun's answer ..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("input[name=options]:radio").change(function() {
                alert($(this).val());

             $("div.divToToggle").hide().filter('#' + $(this).val()).show();
            })
        });

radio btns go here .... 
<div id="1" class="divToToggle" style="display:none">
 ......
</div>

<div id="2" class="divToToggle" style="display:none">
 ....
</div>
```